# RingCentral instance sandbox

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud, ringcentral

We are evaluating RingCentral with Salesforce integration. I would like to know if it is possible to have dev / sandbox instances of RingCentral to develop and test our CTI flows and their integration with Service cloud ?
This dev / sandbox instances will be integrated with our Salesforce sandbox instance.

Thanks for your help

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure RingCentral Sandbox support Salesforce integration as of now and seems only supports production and will redirect to production as per this reference
https://community.ringcentral.com/questions/10432/ring-central-is-not-letting-me-to-select-sandbox-o.html
You can check this query with their technical support team though here
https://support.ringcentral.com/contact-support.html

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by CTI workflow ? If you have test data and don't need to use your production data then you can create a simple app with salesforce integration using Sandbox credentials and test your workflow.

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.